# Microsoft Word. Insert circled minus sign

Tags: microsoft-word, symbols

I need to insert in my document [circled minus sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2296/index.htm). But I can not find it, and I do not want to insert it as symbol.

Typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2296</kbd> inserts different symbol.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex number `2296` converts to `8854` in decimal. Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8854</kbd>. It works for me with `Cambria` font in Word 2003.